# Appending to CSS property

Tags: css, css-animations

The CSS animation property can be given a list of multiple animations.  I want to create a logical subclass in a CSS file that adds an animation to the logical superclass's list of animations.  Here's what I have, but I want to do this without duplicating the fade-in animation:

```
.enter, .enter-left, .enter-right, .enter-top, .enter-bottom {
  animation: fade-in 2s ease-out;
}

.enter-left {
  animation: fade-in 2s ease-out, enter-left 1s ease-out;
}
```

How can I accomplish this, ideally without jquery?  Is there a way to essentially append to a property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS variable like below. The trick is to have multiple animations defined as variable with default values (use a *null* animation that will do nothing) then you simply adjust the values inside the sub classes:

```css
.enter, .enter-left, .enter-right, .enter-top, .enter-bottom {
  animation: fade-in 2s ease-out, var(--anim1,null),var(--anim2,null);
}

.enter-left {
  --anim1:enterleft 1s ease-in;
}
.enter-top {
  --anim1:entertop 1s linear;
}

@keyframes fade-in {
  from {opacity:0;}
}
@keyframes enterleft {
  from {transform:translateX(-100px);}
}
@keyframes entertop {
  from {transform:translateY(100px);}
}

@keyframes back {
  from{background:blue;}
}

@keyframes null{
  0%,100%{font:inherit}
}


.box {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box enter"></div>
<div class="box enter enter-left"></div>
<div class="box enter enter-top" style="--anim2:back 5s"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks!  Could be a little cleaner though:

.enter, .enter-left, .enter-right, .enter-top, .enter-bottom {
  animation: 1s ease-in fade-in, var(--directional);
}

.enter-left {
  --directional: 1s ease-in-out enter-left;
}